# Any references to the ROADEF 2020 Challenge?

Tags: integer-programming, constraint-programming, metaheuristics

The problem description of the challenge is given [here](https://github.com/rte-france/challenge-roadef-2020/raw/master/Challenge_Subject.pdf).

Does anyone has some references to similar problem. I would like to participate but I don't know where to start.

Comment: In the future, please include at least a summary of your problem, rather than just posting an external link. In addition, it helps if you provide at least some indication of what you have tried (even if you don't know where to start) and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This is a maintenance planning problem, here related to the French high-voltage transmission system. By searching for "maintenance planning problem" on the web, you will find a lot of OR literature on the topic.

Now, to start, may we advise you to:

1. entirely read the subject of the challenge;
2. read the input data using your favorite programming language;
3. implement a first, basic solution approach, based on a greedy algorithm or relying on a mathematical optimization solver.

Then, you will be able to iterate, sophisticating your solution approach (or implementing a new, different one).

Note that all the instances given for now (namely, A instances) can be solved to near optimality by LocalSolver through a direct modeling approach. In particular, LocalSolver allows modeling easily and exactly the risk as an external (black-box) function, which is not possible when using traditional MILP solvers. LocalSolver is a commercial product but if you are interested to use it freely for the challenge, you will be welcome.

In a way or another, we encourage you to participate in such a challenge. This is a very formative exercise for real-life OR.